# componentWillReceiveProps() is not called after goBack()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello guys so I have to screens first is Chat Rooms and second is Chat.

In first one I have the chat channels where I select one and then I am going to the second screen where I am actually chatting. In second screen I use `componentWillReceiveProps` for graphql subscriptions. Everything works fine until I use `this.props.navigation.goBack()` and if I return the messages are sent but `componentWillReceiveProps` is never called again.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('I am here')
    if (nextProps.data !== undefined && !nextProps.data.loading) {
      let { subscribeToMore } = this.props.data;
      subscribeToMore({
        document: MESSAGE_ADDED_SUBSCRIPTION,
        updateQuery: (previousResult, { subscriptionData }) => {
          if (!subscriptionData.data) {
            return previousResult;
          }

          const newMessage = subscriptionData.data.messageAdded;

          if (
            previousResult.getMessagesForThisChannel[0] === undefined ||
            previousResult.getMessagesForThisChannel[0].channel._id ===
              newMessage.channel._id
          ) {
            if (
              !previousResult.getMessagesForThisChannel.find(
                n => n._id === newMessage._id
              )
            ) {
              return {
                ...previousResult,
                getMessagesForThisChannel: [
                  { ...newMessage },
                  ...previousResult.getMessagesForThisChannel
                ]
              };
            }
          }

          return previousResult;
        },
        onError: err => console.log(err)
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using react-navigation for navigate screen

Comment: @Tarunkonda Yes as you can see

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, `this.props.navigation.goBack()` by default does not trigger any changes to your redux-state, which is why your props are not refreshed. What you can do is trigger some additional logic (an action) alongside your function that calls `this.props.navigation.goBack()` to notify redux that there has been a change. If you really have no data change at all just simply create a clone of any of your reducers (using map, spread etc) and return it. That should refresh your props.

Comment: I am not using redux

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use react-navigation willFocus event, you can attach the event inside your component in the componentWillMount method:

```
componentWillMount()
  this.props.navigation.addListener(
    'willFocus', () => {
      // do what ever you'd like here...
    }
  );
}
```

then when ever your component is focused again on the screen, it will act just the same as what you were expected from componentWillReceiveProps.